# Cannot ping EC2 instance. Inbound rules set

Tags: networking, ping, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've read several threads  but can not find a solution to following problem:

I have just set up a new instance of an EC2 server running Windows Server 20xx.

I have set up an inbound rule for this instance via the EC2 web interface as follows:

[Inbound Rules EC2 instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcFJK.jpg)

However, I cannot ping the Instance.

Instance sits at ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-x.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Here is the output of ping (from ping.eu/ping):

```
packets transmitted     9
received    0
packet loss     100 %
time    8187 ms
```

Server is up and running [according to AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oraA.jpg)

Comment: but is your OS set to respond to ICMP? By default, I believe it does not.

Answer (score 2):

The software firewall is still running by default on AWS Windows instances.

To enable ping in the OS,

- run "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security"
- Find the "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)" Rule with Remote Address "Any"
- Enable it.

Comment: Good point. Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is becuase PING is disabled by default. We have to enable it. See below post for more infor. 
https://www.screwlinux.com/2019/09/why-i-cant-ping-to-my-aws-ec2-instances.html